# Mediation on an interaction with dichotmous mediator

Tags: regression, logistic, categorical-data, mediation

We are using Tingely et al's mediation R package for mediation analysis. Our study is a 2x2 design, say A (0 and 1) and B (0 and 1), with dichotomous mediator M and continuous dependent measure Y. Our model is
Y = a + b1* A + b2* B + b3* A*B + cX = u
where a, b's,and c are coefficient, u error term.

We found that 
(1) the effect of A alone, i.e. the coefficient b1 was significant, 
(2) the effect of B alone, the coefficient b2 was significant, and 
(3) the interaction effect of A and B, the coefficient b2 was significant.

We wanted to examine how the mediator M mediates the effect in (1), (2) and (3), and were able to conduct the mediation analysis for (1) and (2) by using the moderated mediation feature of the *mediation* package. However, we ran into a problem when we tried to do the mediation in (3).

Would anyone on the forum advise if it is possible, and how, to do the mediation of an interaction effect in an experiment with a 2x2 design?

Comment: Are you asking about how to do this in this particular package, or is your question about whether mediation of interactions is possible at all?

Comment: More generally if this is possible at all, with a dichotomous mediator. A lot of the other packages I've looked at (e.g., PROCESS in SPSS) can do mediation of interactions, but not with dichotomous mediators. Since I've worked most extensively with the R mediation package, if it's possible to do this in this package that would probably be the easiest for me.

Comment: Short answer is yes, the [R] mediation package can do this.